# Two-line spanning number in chapter title

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I try to have the chapter's number in my document twice as big as the title on the left and the two-line chapter title on the right. The number should span two lines, so the two lines of the title are exactly the same size the number is and they are at the same height.

You can see what I achieved so far here:

[image]

The problem now is that the title starts at the bottom of the number, but it should start at the top.

I did this using `titlesec` package:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}{{\fontsize{75}{80}\selectfont\color{chpgrey}{\thechapter~|~}}}{15pt}{}
```

My document class is `scrreprt`.

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve what I want?

Comment: Instead of providing code snippets with references only, rather compile a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that replicates a small instance of your current setup. It will improve the likelihood of answers that exactly match your needs.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use the `explicit` option for `titlesec` and two `\parbox`es (one for the number and the vertical rule, the other one for the title) vertically aligned at the bottom:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\colorlet{chpgrey}{gray!40}

\newcommand\chapnumfont{%
  \fontsize{75}{80}\selectfont\color{chpgrey}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\bfseries\sffamily}
  {}{0pt}
  {{\chapnumfont\parbox[b]{3cm}{%
      \thechapter}\vrule width3pt depth0.2ex}\hspace{15pt}%
    \parbox[b]{\linegoal}{\Huge\raggedright#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter Title}
\chapter{Test Chapter Title Spanning Two Lines}

\end{document}
```

An image for a one line title:

[image]

An image for a title spanning two lines:

[image]

Feel free to adjust the widths of the boxes according to your needs.